# Advanced Wordpress categories listing

Tags: wordpress

well at least for me this is advanced. I have one jewerly site with brands. For now i have fixed number of brands like 10 of them. I want each brand to have its own page with unique header/image/title/logo. When u enter brand landing page you see brand products. Click on read  more hows product details page. Problem is that client want later to add himself new category new brand. And brand must be shown under menu and one slider on homepage. What is best way to do it ? What is proper way. So you have main menu -> our collections -> addlers for example. I want to list there all products from Adler but have unique header then other brands.
Link is -> http://www.mobilecommz.com/istanawordpress/our-collections/

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is how we do it in our blog.

Install the following plugins:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/widgets-on-pages/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-posts-widget/

Than create a brand Page and use the shortcode of the widget on page plugin. Set up the widget with ultimate posts. Now you can filter by category or something.

Comment: This look interesting will try that. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Hello, 
i tried plugins you send me and they are working great! My only question and concern is that my site is responsive. So i need yo add twitter bootstrap classes like col-md etc to post template. how can i use that because plugin use its own styling? can i alter div and html structure of created psots?

Comment: I would not recommend using boostrap for the exact same reason you mentioned: adding the div is a deep dive in the plugin. I would suggest adding only css to the existing classes. Why do you especially bootstrap?

Comment: because every site i am making is in bootstrap :)